# php mvc router not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller

i have php mvc project .
This is my router class.
router class job is include controller in main index page of website.
its work on localhost but when i uploaded on my host not working
what i do ?

```
<?php
class route
{
    function __construct()
    {
        if(empty($_GET['url']))
        {
            $url = "index";
        }
        else
        {
            $url = $_GET['url'];
        }
        $url = explode("/",$url);
        if(!empty($url[0]))
        {
            $controllername = "controllers/".$url[0].".php";
            if(file_exists($controllername))
            {
                require($controllername);
                $object = new $url[0];
                //$object->loadmodel($url[0]);
                if(!empty($url[1]))
                {
                    if(method_exists($object,$url[1]))
                    {
                        if(!empty($url[2]))
                        {
                            $object->$url[1]($url[2]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $object->$url[1]();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my error in error_log

> thrown in /home/mogeir/public_html/libs/route.php PHP Notice:  Array
>   to string conversion in /home/mogeir/public_html/libs/route.php on
>   line 33 PHP Notice:  Undefined property: admin::$Array in
>   /home/mogeir/public_html/libs/route.php on line 33 PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/mogeir/public_html/libs/route.php:33

Comment: please explain your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following function call forms instead - the commented ones are correct alternatives too. See [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
if (!empty($url[2])) {
    $object->{$url[1]}($url[2]);

    // Alternative 1
    // call_user_func(array($object, $url[1]), $url[2]);

    // Alternative 2
    // call_user_func_array(array($object, $url[1]), array($url[2]));
} else {
    $object->{$url[1]}();

    // Alternative 1
    // call_user_func(array($object, $url[1]));

    // Alternative 2
    // call_user_func_array(array($object, $url[1]), array());
}
```

You said:

> its work on localhost but when i uploaded on my host not working what i do ?

That has to do with the error reporting activation or with difference in PHP version.

Comment: A note: When an error occurres, you should redirect to an error controller, passing into the action of your choice the corresponding error message as argument.